# Filter orders by product

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am newbie in SQL development. I am not good in SQL join :( .

please help me to write a SQL query to extract the following fileds from the below tables for the product "**A Home Portable Laser Hair Remover**".

**Fileds required:**

orders.id, orders.order_price, orders.purchase_date, customers.email, product_orders.qty, products.name

**Table 1: orders**

```
id  customer_id order_price purchase_date
1   1                   0.20    12/6/2011
2   2                   0.20    12/6/2011
3   1                   0.20    12/6/2011
4   1                   0.20    12/6/2011
5   1                   0.20    12/7/2011
6   3                   199.00  12/7/2011
7   4                   199.00  12/7/2011
8   5                   199.00  12/7/2011
9   6                   199.00  12/7/2011
10  7                   199.00  12/7/2011
```

**Table 2 : customers**

```
id  email                   name
1   aa@dealboard.com.au aa
2   bb@dealboard.com.au bb
3   cc@live.com.au          cc
4   dd@acgglobal.com    dd
5   ee.heinrich@det.nsw.edu.au  ee
6   ff@optusnet.com.au  ff
7   ssy@hotmail.com         ss
```

**table 3: products**

```
id  name
1   A Home Portable Laser Hair Remover
2   Ipad
3   android
4   Asus
5   s
6   10 inch Android
7   A Fabric Steamer Cleaner
8   A Magnetic Fly Screen Door
9   pillopw
10  LCD
```

**table 4: product_orders**

```
       id orders_id product_id qty
        1   1      1         1
        2   2      1         1
        3   3      1         1
        4   4      1         1
        5   5      2         1
        6   6      1         1
        7   7      1         1
        8   8      1         1
        9   9      1         1
        10  10     1         1
```

i wanna extract the all the order for the product id 1 or filter orders by product

please help me

Comment: you should give a sample table of result that you want to extract.

Comment: Hi, i have given 4 tables as example. i just need the following fields from those tables "orders.id, orders.order_price, orders.purchase_date, customers.email, product_orders.qty, products.name". thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like you want to join across all tables:

```
select orders.id, orders.order_price, orders.purchase_date, customers.email,
    product_orders.qty, products.name from orders, customers, product_orders,
    products where
    orders.customer_id = customers.id and
    product_orders.order_id = orders.id and
    products.id = product_orders.product_id and
    products.id = 1
```

Comment: yes, quite sort of. i need to export some reports with various conditions. thx for your query. after i try, i will let u know , its working or not. thanks.

Comment: Thank u very much "Tim", awesome. are u software engineer?

Answer (score 0):

Test this-

```
SELECT product_orders.id, OC.order_price, OC.purchase_date, OC.email, product_orders.qty, products.name
FROM product_orders 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT orders.id as oid,orders.order_price,orders.purchase_date,customers.id as cid ,customers.email,customers.name
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN customers
ON orders.customer_id=cutomers.id) as OC
ON
product_orders.orders_id=OC.oid AND
product_orders.product_id=1
LEFT JOIN
products
ON
product_orders.product_id=products.name
```